# Migrating a project from Flash Builder 4.0 to Flash Builder 4.5 is producing the error "The required skin state 'disabledWithPrompt' is missing"

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to migrate a project from Flash Builder 4.0 to Flash Builder 4.5. After Flash Builder prompts me to choose my new SDK, I choose 4.5, Then I get the following error:" error "The required skin state 'disabledWithPrompt' is missing".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the missing state to your component, example

```
<states>
    <state name="missingState"/>
</states>
```

Comment: Yep, that's because Flex 4.5 TextInput supports prompt display.